# vue.js not removing row

Tags: html, vue.js, laravel-blade

I am busy making a dynamic form using Vue.js and at the moment, I appear to have everything correct except the remove function. It's all correctly configured as far as I see, yet the console in my browser displays the error "this.rows.$remove is not a function".

Does anyone know the solution for this, or can help me out finding the solution? Thanks in advance.

======================================

**Here is the HTML for the page where the form is displayed:**

```
<html>  
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>M06 Property-create</title>

    <!-- Including nessecary javascript sources -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.js"></script>

</head>


{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'property.store')) !!}

@include('properties.form')

{!! Form::close() !!}

<a href="/property">Return</a>

<script> //This script handles the adding / removal of label/text fields upon clicking the add label / remove label button
    var app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            rows: [
                {name: ""}
            ]
        },
        methods: {
            addRow: function () {
                this.rows.push({name: ""});
            },
            removeRow: function (row) {
                console.log(row);
                this.rows.$remove(row);
            }
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

======================================

**Here is the HTML / Blade for the form itself that is included:**

```
{!! Form::label('label', Lang::get('misc.label')) !!}
{!! Form::text('label', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) !!}
<br>
{!! Form::label('internal_name', Lang::get('misc.internal_name')) !!}
{!! Form::text('internal_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) !!}
<br>
{!! Form::label('field_type_id', Lang::get('misc.fieldtype_name')) !!}
{!! Form::select('field_type_id', $fieldTypes) !!}

<div class="dropdown box">
<div class="multi-field-wrapper">

    <div class="multi-fields">
        <div class="multi-field">

            <div id="app">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <button type="button" class="button btn-primary" @click="addRow">Add label</button>

                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Label</strong></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr v-for="row in rows">
                            <td><input type="text" v-model="row.name"></td>
                            <td><button type="button" class="button btn-primary" @click="removeRow(row)">Remove</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>    

        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
<br>
{!! Form::label('property_group_id', Lang::get('misc.group_name')) !!}
{!! Form::select('property_group_id', $groups) !!}
<br>         
{!! Form::label('description', Lang::get('misc.description')) !!}
{!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) !!}
<br>
<br>
{!! Form::submit(Lang::get('misc.save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'id' => 'btn-save']) !!}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `$remove` method has been deprecated in vue 2.0, so I assume you are using that. You will need to use splice instead:

HTML:

```
<tr v-for="(row, index) in rows">
  <td><input type="text" v-model="row.name"></td>
  <td><button type="button" class="button btn-primary" @click="removeRow(index)">Remove</button></td>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
removeRow: function (index) {
  console.log(index);
  this.rows.splice(index,1);
}
```

You can see the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/rLes3nww/

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much @craig_h !

Comment: Also, is it possible to notify vue.js of their outdated guide? Because I got the $remove from their site's guide. (2.0 version)

Answer (score 0):

Its really irritating to refer to the guide and then to find out that it is deprecated.

Anyway I found this as reference of which one is deprecated or not.
[Reference to deprecated Vue stuff](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2873)